# Create Groups Without Repeating Previous Groupings

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, heuristics

I have created a random group creator, but random doesn't really guarantee that you work with people you haven't worked with before. If someone was able to generate a "Random Group Generator With History" that tracked previous groups and avoided putting people in groups with the same people over and over, I would definitely use it! Does anyone know how to do this?

For clarity: Given an array of strings

```
["Jason", "Kim", "Callie", "Luke"]
```

and an array of previous pairings (also arrays)

```
[[["Jason", "Kim"], ["Callie", "Luke"]], [["Jason", "Luke"], ["Callie", "Kim"]]]
```

return groupings with the fewest number of repeat group members

```
[["Jason", "Callie"], ["Luke", "Kim"]]
```

I'm imagining that the number I am trying to minimize is the number of repeat partners. So for each pair of two people, for every time they have already been on a team, if the result puts them on the same team, the result would have a score of that. For the example, the "scoring" to arrive at the return value could look like this:

```
["Jason", "Kim"] have a score of 1, they have been paired together before
["Callie", "Luke"] have a score of 1, they have been paired together before
["Jason", "Luke"] have a score of 1, they have been paired together before
["Callie", "Kim"] have a score of 1, they have been paired together before
["Jason", "Callie"] have a score of 0, they have not been paired together before
["Luke", "Kim"] have a score of 0, they have not been paired together before
```

Choose the sets that cover the entire list while generating the smallest score. In this case, the pairings ["Jason", "Callie"] and ["Luke", "Kim"] cover the entire set, and have a score of 0 (no repeated groupings) and therefore it is an optimal solution (0 being the best possible outcome).

This is probably the wrong way to do this (since I'm imagining it would take n squared time), but hopefully it gives a sense of what I'm trying to optimize for. This would not need to be a perfect optimization, just a "decent answer" that doesn't put the same groups together every single time.

Ideally, it would be able to handle any size group, and also be able to handle the fact that someone might be out that day (not all people will be in all of the arrays). I would love a javascript answer, but I should be able to translate if someone can come up with the logic.

Comment: please add some thoughts how do you get from second line to third line, the result.

Comment: you may look for weighted random sampling

Comment: @NinaScholz I hope that helps? I tried to add a much more in-depth explanation of those steps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could collect all pairings in an object and count. Then take only the ones with a smaller count.

```js
function getKey(array) {
    return array.slice().sort().join('|');
}

var strings = ["Jason", "Kim", "Callie", "Luke"],
    data = [[["Jason", "Kim"], ["Callie", "Luke"]], [["Jason", "Luke"], ["Callie", "Kim"]]],
    object = {},
    i, j,
    keys;

for (i = 0; i < strings.length - 1; i++) {
    for (j = i + 1; j < strings.length; j++) {
        object[getKey([strings[i], strings[j]])] = 0;
    }
}

data.forEach(function (a) {
    a.forEach(function (b, i) {
        object[getKey(b)]++;
    });
});

keys = Object.keys(object).sort(function (a, b) {
    return object[b] - object[a];
});

keys.forEach(function (k) {
    console.log(k, object[k]);
});

console.log(object);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: This is a super clever way to get the counts. This is definitely where I want to start, but how do I "Take only the ones with a smaller count." Is there an easy way to take the ones with a smaller count and still guarantee full coverage (everyone is in a group)?